# Selecting rows from other tables based on the first table using SQL

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

I have three T-SQL statements that I'd like to combine into one, so it is just a single call to the database, not three.

```
SELECT * FROM Clients
```

The first one, selects every client from the Clients table.

```
SELECT * FROM History
```

The second one, selects all the history entries from the History table. I then use some code to find the first history for each client. i.e. first history in the table for `ClientID` gets set into the `HasHistory` column for that `ClientID`.

```
SELECT * FROM Actions
```

The final one, I get all the actions from the action table. I then use some code to find the last action for each client. i.e. last action in the table for `ClientID` gets set into the `LastAction` column for that `ClientID`.

So I'm wondering if there is a way to write an SQL statement like this for example? Note this is not real SQL, just pseudo code to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Clients

AND 

SELECT First History Row 
FROM History 
WHERE History.ClientID = Clients.ClientID

AND 

SELECT Last Action Row 
FROM Actions 
WHERE Actions.ClientID = Clients.ClientID
```

Comment: Hint: `INNER JOIN` or `UNION` with `TOP 1` depending on what you are after

Comment: Does TOP 1 get the first row? Sorry if that is a dumb question. I've very little experience with SQL, so don't know what INNER JOIN, UNION or TOP 1 means.

Comment: Just looked up UNION, but I don't think that will work according to this. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

Comment: You should start by understanding `INNER JOIN` which is a fundamental component of SQL. Then you need to find a column in your `History` and `Actions` tables that indicates what the 'last' record is. Is there a date or number column in this table that indicates this?

Comment: Well to answer you’d need to show us all the columns for each table and what the expected results would be

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you can do this, but here is one example. I'll work on it a bit at a time to explain what we are doing. You haven't shown us the table design, so the column names are a guess, but you should get the idea.

First, you have to somehow mark which history rows you care about. One way to do this is to do a query that puts an order number on every history row, that starts from 1 with every new client, and orders them by date. This way, the first history row for each client (the one you want) always has a row number of one. This would look something like

```
SELECT
    *, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY clientID ORDER BY historyDate) AS orderNo 
FROM
    History
```

You would do something similar with actions, except you want the latest action, not the first one, so your order by column has to be in reverse order - you do this by telling the ORDER BY to use descending order, something like this

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY clientID ORDER BY actionDate DESC) AS orderNo 
FROM Actions
```

You should now have two queries where the only rows you want are marked with a order number of one. What you do now is start with your first query, and join to these other two queries so that you only join to the orderno = 1 rows. Then all the data you want will be available in one row. You have to decide which join type to use - an inner join will only return Clients that actually have a history and an action. If you want to see clients that have no rows at all in the other tables, you need to use a left outer join. But your final query (you only need this one) will look something like

```
SELECT
    C.*, H.*, A.*
FROM
    Clients C
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT
         *, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY clientID ORDER BY historyDate) AS orderNo 
     FROM History) H ON H.clientID = C.clientID AND H.orderNo = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT
         *, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY clientID ORDER BY actionDate DESC) AS orderNo 
     FROM Actions) A ON A.clientID = C.clientID AND A.orderNo = 1
```

What this says is: take Clients (which we'll call C), then for each row, try and join to (match a row from) the History query we looked at above (which we'll call H) where the client ID is the same and the orderNo is 1 - ie the first history row. It also does the same for the Actions query.